# vim syntax match alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, vim

I have log files I want to make a bit more easy to read using vim's syntax feature.

At the beginning of the line is the error number which is a letter followed by a 4 digit number (for example F1000).

The command
    `syn match error '/^[F]\d\{4}'`
works well but it also matches hex code contained in the error.

Is there a way that I can specify that the pattern should match only if it's at the beginning of the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 syn match error '^[A-Z]\d\{4}'
```

`^` stands for start-of-line
 and `A-Z` matches any uppercase letter.